# Korean sentences being split randomly

Tags: html, css, unicode

I'm facing a problem here: I have a text in Korean decimal Unicode and the text is displayed in 4 columns and many rows (as it's the answers of a language test). The problem is that because the width of each answer is 20%, the sentence splits randomly in the middle of the word when it doesn't fit, instead of in the spaces between words. I don't know how to treat this, since this text is loaded and displayed automatically from a database.

The HTML code for each one of the 4 columns is like this:

```
<table class="courses" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="100%" style="font-size:13px;">
  <tbody>
    <td width="20%">
     <p align="center">
       <input name="a[X]" value=1" type="radio">
       <br>
       <?php echo "&#48148;&#49240;&#47732; &#44032;&#51648; &#47560;&#49464;&#50836;" ?> // this comes from a DB, its the unicodes of the korean characters<br>
    </p>
   </td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

What could I do to fix this and, when it doesn't fit, avoid splitting randomly, but do it when a sentence ends? If you notice in the Unicode codes, you can tell there's a space between ;면 &#44032, but it breaks just anywhere, the same for all the text.

(Note that there aren't any encoding problems, the Korean characters are displayed properly. And it doesn't happen with other languages like Swedish or Spanish).

**EDIT**

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZkNsa/).

Note that in the example, the first answer is split in the last two characters, when that word has five characters, so should be split 3 chars before.

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers? I think the question might be browser-specific, so it should at least mention something about browser(s) affected.

Comment: How big is the container that this table resides in? There are very few characters in your example. I'm not seeing any unnatural/unexpected breaks.

Comment: It happens in Chrome and Firefox, didn't have the chance to test with IE.

Comment: Could you provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ with the markup/css for your table and a large enough sample of characters that we can play with?

Comment: I edited the question with the jsfiddle example :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Line breaking for CJK (Chinese/Japanese/Korean) text can be quite problematic given the current state of web standards.

There is not too much you can do in a language-agnostic manner; CSS level 3 defines [related attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#line-breaking) (`line-break` and `word-break`), but I 'm not so sure what the support level is accross modern browsers (obviously not-so-modern browsers are entirely out of the picture).

Comment: Beat me to it. For reference, the wikipedia article on [word wrap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_wrap#Word_wrapping_in_text_containing_Chinese.2C_Japanese.2C_and_Korean) "In Chinese, Japanese, and Korean, each Han character is normally considered a word, and therefore word wrapping can usually occur before and after any Han character."

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't really matter as Korean can be split anywhere anyway. See this screenshot from Chosun.com:

[image]

The words are cut anywhere, seemingly randomly. You don't need to worry about hyphenation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same issue and I think the best solution is to wrap each word in a span with `white-space: nowrap;`. This makes sure there won't be any line break inside the word.

See this JSFiddle for a proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/we7jx08r/. When you change body's width, you'll notice that the line breaks are always correct.

See http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/ for `white-space: nowrap` browser support (IE5.5+, FF1+, Safari 1+).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are just encountering the default behavior of `white-space`. You could take a look at the CSS [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/white-space) property and try something like `pre`.

Comment: I just tried but it doesn't work since using the pre (or similar properties) the sentences don't break and the width of the table grows very much

Answer (score 0):

You could try a solution I worked on a while ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46714474/2114953

That is, if you like to use JS in order to wrap each word into span HTML elements and then use CSS display: inline-block to force words to go to new lines if need be.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking in to this for a project I'm working on. I think https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#line-breaking covers this, particularly "Example 5":

> As another example, Korean has two styles of line-breaking: between any two Korean syllables (word-break: normal) or, like English, mainly at spaces (word-break: keep-all).

Indeed, the default behavior of Google Chrome (version 61) is that it breaks on the syllables (I assume as I don't speak or read Korean)

Setting word-break: all, seems to override this behavior and put line wraps in on white spaces only.

Answer (score 0):

`word-break: keep-all;` Fixed it for me. I added this if the user is view the site in Korean specifically.

`word-break: keep-all;` -> "Word breaks should not be used for Chinese/Japanese/Korean (CJK) text. Non-CJK text behavior is the same as value 'normal'" (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp)