# Dealing with Korean text breaking words

Tags: css, cjk, word-break

I am building a website where I am displaying korean text. The client (US local) is being very unhappy because the text is breaking in the middle of words. As example of this, here is an image: Red background text being one word.

[image]

I have tried to use

```
word-break: keep-all;
```

but it isn't supported in Chrome/Safari.

What am I able to do? I have searched the web for hours and got nothing. Is this something that is expected in cjk sites or is there a solution that I haven't found.

It is a responsive site, so I can't put in hard breaks, or fake it.

demo: http://codepen.io/cibgraphics/pen/tqzfG

Comment: Please post a testable example (HTML code and text content).

Comment: I am not sure why your client is upset, because native Korean users are not very sensitive on word-breaks. Actually every lines in the example are breaking single word into two lines. Then, it's also weird why only the red-block part is noticed.

Comment: I'll post this as a comment since I'm going to point you to a link, but see if this solution can be adapted to your app:  https://kopepasah.com/tutorial/fixing-broken-korean-words-in-wordpress-titles/

Comment: Please tell your client that uneven space width is really annoying presentation to Koreans.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use jquery plugin - https://github.com/mytory/jquery-word-break-keep-all

This plugin is for it. IE has CSS property word-break: keep-all; but other browser has not.

Comment: This is what we ended up doing. Finally was able to talk to a Korean on site, and found out that while they are sensitive to line-breaks (in his words it "annoys them") there is no solution in place that is acceptable because they design around it. This is easy for them because they have yet to adapt responsive design. Design around it, and it's a non-issue. Still... doesn't help me other than this plugin which has mostly worked, but has caused some layout problems which is easier to fix than a large site full of word breaks.

Answer (score 2):

The SPACE character generally allows a line break. This is not affected by the [`word-break`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#word-break-property) property. To disallow a line break, use NO-BREAK SPACE instead of SPACE, e.g. `십&nbsp;니까`. Alternatively, wrap a sequence of characters that should not be broken in a `span` element and set `white-space: nowrap` on it.

Comment: I appreciate the comment but this problem will be affecting a very large site with very dynamic content so the solution either needs to be a javascript one (that doesn't impact performace) or a css one.

spans just wont do.

Comment: @Mechwd, then you need to define an algorithm for preventing line breaks and implement it in JavaScript (e.g. so that spaces are replaced by no-break spaces *according to specific rules* that you have defined).

Answer (score 2):

Use the CSS rule `word-break: keep-all`. It's now [supported in all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break#Browser_compatibility) but Microsoft Edge (a change since 2014 when the accepted answer above was posted).

Answer (score 1):

Add both `line-break:strict` and `word-break:keep-all` into your CSS. This helps solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a mixed solution in which you use CSS and JS in order to simulate words and then move them to a new line if the width is not enough.

The test I did uses a CSS class with display inline-block and then wraps each Korean word into spans. 
CSS

```
.korean-word {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

The use a JS/jQuery code like this:

```
var p = $(".hero__description");
var text = p.text();
var nospace = /(\S+)/g;
var p1 = text.replace(nospace, "<span class='korean-word'>$1</span>");
p.html(p1);
```

The code simply takes in a text, looks at things which are NOT spaces and then puts those things into span HTML elements. This way you force a word to go to new line.